# mod_rewrite - Rule question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

For dynamic pages, I have all requests going to product.php page, and sorting through the params.  The rules are:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product.php?cat_slug=$1&sub_slug=$2&product_slug=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ product.php?cat_slug=$1&sub_slug=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)$ product.php?cat_slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I now want a rule to handle ALL other requests to go to page.php?id=$1.  Something like:

([^/]+) page.php?id=$1

Unfortunately that doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the begin and end of the string and exclude the substitution paths:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(page|product)\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ page.php?id=$1
```

Comment: cool, that almost worked for me, except none of my previous product rules work now (as in the code block in my question).  They all get directed to the page.php instead of product.php